# Error on reimporting GitHub repository to the developer story

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I recently finished to add a new project into my GitHub account, called "Sender". I added it also successfully to my developer story tag. Then I found out that by mistake I uploaded the code with some hard coded credentials, and had to remove the entire repository from GitHub and to upload it again. And so I did.

To be on the safe side, I deleted it also from the developer story, and try to re-added it again. But then, I got error from Stack Overflow (image attached). It's just not responding. And I see the error in the console in the developer tools. I tried to logout and login and try again, but it didn't solve the issue.
What can I do?

Thanks.

[image]

#### Update

The bug has been fixed. Thanks all.

Comment: I tried again and it worked. Question closed.